# PHP Contact Form fallback for failing email transmission

Tags: php, email

I am working on my new business website right now. I am implementing a simple contact form and send all the needed data via email to my email address.

If the email transmission does not work for whatever reason, I don't want to display an error message, but try to receive the request in a different way, if possible.

I already thought about some fallback email addresses (on other servers) to send the requests to. But I am not very happy with that idea. Do you have a better one? Am I too afraid of that unlikely scenario?

Comment: Store the requests in a database before sending the email; If you fail to send the email you'd still have the data in your database.

Comment: take it even broader: store the request SOMEHOW, on top of trying to send the email. the email fails, you've still got this other "somehow" to fall back on.

Comment: I thought about that as well. But you don't want to check for requests manually in the database every day (at least once).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using php `mail();` function.

```
$email = mail($to,$subject,$message);

if($email === false){
    //Store that email in database
    //Notify yourself with another email
}
```

But this validation doesn't mean you email will deliver. its upto your mail server to deliver emails and it can fail and you can do nothing about it.

The other alternative will be to use Pear php mail packages https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php

Using this you can use `SMTP` of other servers eg gmail which is less likely to fail. if for some reasons its failed you should find that mail in sent box(i am not sure about this)

There are other mail services you can use which guarantee mail deliver.

**As you asked**

PHP `mail()` should not be used for bulk emails.PHP says

> It is worth noting that the `mail()` function is not suitable for larger
>   volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP
>   socket for each email, which is not very efficient. For the sending of
>   large amounts of email, see the » [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue), and » [PEAR::Mail_Queue](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue)
>   packages.

Comment: Thank you, I will look more into Pear. But is that what people do or is it usual just to use php's mail() and pray it worked?